# The interior fan on my 2012 Fusion squeaks: lubricate it?

Tags: ford, interior, fan

I recently purchased a used 2012 Ford Fusion. When the interior fan is blowing at a low speed (1 or 2), it makes an annoying squeak. Can I put a few drops of lubricant somewhere to fix this? Does it require pulling the entire dash apart? Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are a lot of people with this problem! The blower is part #: MM-1091. Some of us have no warranty. Certainly there is an actual solution to fixing the part, since they all go bad so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what your mileage is like, your Fusion came with a 36m/36k mile bumper-to-bumper warranty. The B2B warranty also includes adjustments, which this actually is. If you are not over 36,000 miles, take it to your local Ford dealership and have them fix it. Warranties transfer with the vehicle unless specified (Hyundai's Powertrain warranty past 60k miles does not transfer unless vehicle goes to a relative). The B2B should transfer and they have to fix it. I know this doesn't answer your original question, it's something which is not well advertised and will get your issue fixed.

**EDIT:** Since you have a billion miles on this thing, yes you will have to tear the dash apart, but I doubt a drop of oil will fix it. The fan motors have bushings which are sealed. These bushings are pre-lubed for the life of the fan. The good news is, they should have made it fairly easy to get to. Before you go destroying everything, though check to see if the cabin air filter needs replacing. Since your car has one, it may be shot, causing a "vacuum" type interference with the fan. These should be replace every 15k miles or something (check you owners manual or online for scheduled maintenance). If this doesn't get you fixed, these may actually be something interfering with the fan, so check for that. I'm suggestion a leaf or some such might have got in to where the fan is.

If that is a nogo, you will probably need to change out the fan. The replacement part name is "blower motor". The Motorcraft part number is: MM1091 (Alternate/OEM Part Number(s): 8E5Z19805A, MM1063).

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Alas, I bought the thing with 90000 miles on it. (It was a lease return, and I have no idea how they kept the paint so nice while driving the thing nonstop...)

Comment: @Brannon ... Non-stop is no lie. I hope you got a good price for it.